# How to set globally my JEE REST client headers?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, http-headers, jax-rs

Is there any way to set globally my REST headers?
I tried to combine some JAX-RS tricks but without effects.

All my REST services have those annotations:

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
```

and

```
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
```

All I want in the end is to finish with headers:

```
Accept:[application/json]
Content-Type:[application/json;charset=utf-8]
```

...without touching REST classes, only by configuration.
Is there any simply way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, no help from the outside so I did it :)

I used `HttpServletResponseWrapper` from `javax.servlet.http` to set headers.

I also used `FilterChain` from `javax.servlet` to be sure to not let anythink else knock-knock :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can easily do this. Create a BaseResource class and extend it wherever you are creating Classes for your Endpoint.

```
public abstract BaseResource {
    @HeaderParam("username")
    private String username;

    @HeaderParam("user-ip")
    private String userIp;
    public String getUserAccount () {
        return userAccount;
    }

    public final String getUserIP() {
        return userIp;
    }
}
```

using these methods you can easily access the header values.

Comment: Thanks for this answer but actually I cannot touch code in REST services, right now I'm searching for ```ContainerRequestFilter```.

Comment: Oh I do not need to take those headers, I need to edit them before sending request.